# URL handling for each post in a Blog using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, blogs

I am making a Blogging Engine using ASP.NET MVC3,

I have my database design in place, I was wondering on how to handle URL of each post in mvc3 ?

Say for example, a user write two post with titles like

- My first post
- My second post

So now, I can insert these titles and content of these post into my database.

What I dont know is how to show these post with url like ...

- www.example.com/2012/06/my-first-post
- www.example.com/2012/07/my-second-post

I am not sure if this is very easy in MVC or not, please can someone guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yasser,

this will get you started:

Global.asax replace default route with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{year}/{month}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "PostGroup" } 
);
```

Your action method in your Posts controller will look something like:

```
public ActionResult PostGroup(int year, int month)
{
    var viewModel = _serviceTasks.All<Post>()
        .Where(x => x.PostDate.Year == year
            && x.PostDate.Month == month);
    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

This should get you > 50% into the guts of your solution, the remainder being your own hard toil :-0.